# Norm of a $2$-tuple of operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, inequalities, operator-theory

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space and $K_1,K_2$ are bounded linear operators on $E$.

Let $\omega(K_1)$ and $\omega(K_2)$ be the numerical radius of $K_1$ and $K_2$ respectively. That is
\begin{align*}
\omega(K_i) = \sup\Big\{|{\langle K_ix, x\rangle}|:\, \, x\in E, {\|x\|}= 1\Big\},\quad i=1,2.
\end{align*}

Let
$$\|(K_1,K_2)\|:=\sup\Big\{|{\langle K_1x, y\rangle}|^2+|{\langle K_2x, y\rangle}|^2:\, \, x,y\in E, {\|x\|}={\|y\|}= 1\Big\}.$$

> I want to find prove whether or not the following inequality
> $$\omega(K_1)^2+\omega(K_2)^2\leq \|(K_1,K_2)\|,$$
> holds.

It's clear that
\begin{align*}
  \|(K_1,K_2)\| & \geq |{\langle K_1x, y\rangle}|^2+|{\langle K_2x, y\rangle}|^2,
\end{align*}
for all $x,y\in E, {\|x\|}={\|y\|}= 1$. In particular

\begin{align*}
  \|(K_1,K_2)\| & \geq |{\langle K_1x, x\rangle}|^2+|{\langle K_2x, x\rangle}|^2,
\end{align*}
for all $x\in E, {\|x\|}= 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand\C{\Bbb C}\newcommand\om{\omega}$A counterexample is given by $E=\mathbb C^2$ and $K_1(x_1,x_2)=(x_1,0)$ and $K_2(x_1,x_2)=(0,x_2)$ for complex $x_1,x_2$.

Indeed, then $\om(K_1)=\om(K_2)=1=\|(K_1,K_2)\|$.